# Change display of WP REST API Date with Vue js on Laravel

Tags: laravel, date, vue.js

Hei guys so I want to show date where my post created at wp, I'm using vue js now I can show date with some weird format it look like this

> 2018-08-06T18:29:59

this is my code in .vue

```
<div class="date-below"><p>created at {{post.date | date}}</p></div>
```

I want to showing date look like this format

> dd/mm/yyyy

can you guys help me how to change the display ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can suggest is to use computed property for formatting your date. This should be something like this -

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    post : {
        //Other post data, all data pulled from Laravel API
        date: "2018-08-06T18:29:59",
        }
    },
    computed: {
       postDate() {
           var date = new Date(this.post.date);
           var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
           var day = date.getDate();
           var year = date.getFullYear();
           month = (month < 10) ? "0"+month:month;
           day = (day < 10) ? "0"+day:day;
           return day+"/"+month+"/"+year;
       }
    }
});
```

And in your template part

```
<div class="date-below"><p>created at {{postDate | date}}</p></div>
```

I am not aware of format string in JavaScript like PHP have.  Please correct me any one who know how to use date formatting string in JavaScript.